# Mounted S3 on EC2 (Directories are not accessible from AWS UI)

Tags: amazon-s3

Some quick questions:

1. Does S3 support soft link?
2. On mounted S3 on EC2, I can't access the created directory in Linux EC2 instance from AWS UI, however created files are accessible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is an **object store**, not a filesystem. It has a specific set of APIs for uploading, listing, downloading, etc but it does not behave like a normal filesystem.

**There are some utilities that can mount S3 as a filesystem** (eg [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/), [Cloudberry Drive](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-cloud-storage-online-hard-drive.aspx), [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon)), but in the background these utilities are actually translating requests into API calls. This can cause some issues -- for example, you can modify a 100MB file on a local disk by just writing one by to disk. If you wish to modify one byte on S3, you must upload the whole object again. This can cause synchronization problems between your computer and S3, so such methods are not recommended for production situations. (However, they're a great way of uploading/downloading initial data.)

A good in-between option is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has commands such as `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3 sync`, which are reliable ways to upload/download/sync files with Amazon S3.

To answer your questions...

**Amazon S3 does not support a "soft link" (symbolic link).** Amazon S3 is an object store, not a file system, so it only contains objects. Objects can also have meta-data that is often for cache control, redirection, classification, etc.

**Amazon S3 does not support directories (sort of).** Amazon S3 objects are kept within buckets, and the buckets are 'flat' -- they do not contains directories/sub-folders. However, it does **maintain the illusion of directories**. For example, if file `bar.jpg` is stored in the `foo` directory, then the Key (filename) of the object is `foo/bar.jpg`. This makes the object 'appear' to be in the `foo` directory, but that's not how it is stored. The AWS Management Console maintains this illusion by allowing users to create and open Folders, but the actual data is stored 'flat'.

This leads to some interesting behaviours:

- **You do not need to create a directory to store an object in the directory.** 
  Directories don't exist. Just store a file called `images/cat.jpg` and the `images` directory magically appears (even though it doesn't exist).
- **You cannot rename objects.** The Key (filename) is a unique identifier for the object. To 'rename' an object, you must copy it to a new Key and delete the original.
- **You cannot rename a directory.** They don't exist. Instead, rename all the objects within the directory (which really means you have to copy the objects, then delete their old versions).
- **You might create a directory but not see it.** Amazon S3 keeps track of `CommonPrefixes` to assist in listing objects by path, but it doesn't create traditional directories. So, don't get worried if you create a (pretend) directory and then don't see it. Just store your object with a full-path name and the directory will 'appear'.

The above-mentioned utilities take all this into account when allowing an Amazon S3 bucket to be mounted. They translate 'normal' filesystem commands into Amazon S3 API calls, but they can't do everything (eg they might emulate renaming a file but they typically won't let you rename a directory).